Google Business Profile Acquiring All Locations
How do I go about getting all of our locations?  I have a location that some random person has taken and they will not relinquish it and then how can I quickly verify each location?

Here are Google's guidelines for verifying ownership of the business and or locations. These go hand-in-hand with their guidelines on claiming business and locations.

If you own a business that you want to be verified on GMP Google My Profile you still can do that by following the verification process which every business has to follow.
I don't get your first point clearly "How can someone randomly take your location?"
If you have multiple locations add them one-by-one in the GMP, add all the details and send them for verification. Complete the verification process and you will own them. And Google systems are now smart enough to catch all the fake profiles.
